# when i use #element:target #otherelement it is not working

Tags: html, css

So Im trying to use `:target` in this way:

```
#Menu:target #buttons {
    dipslay: flex !Important;
}
```

This doesnt work at all. It is not even shown in the DOM. This is the HTML structure:

```
<a href="#Menu" id="Menu">&#9776;</a>
<span id="buttons">
</span>
```

So what am i doing wrong?
It should work like this example:
https://www.html-seminar.de/rwd/nav-responsive-design-ohne-js.htm#nav-menue

Resize this Website to 500px and click on the blue button on the top-right corner.

There you can see that the menu is opening up when you click the button...

Answer (score 0):

Your `span#buttons` is outside of the `a#Menu` tag, but to work correctly, it should be inside... Also just FYI, it's better to use a class to mark buttons, just to avoid possible duplication of pretty general ID `buttons` in future.

```
<a href="#Menu" id="menu">
   &#9776;
   <span class="menu-buttons">
   </span>
</a>
```

And CSS will look like this:

```
#menu:target .menu-buttons {
    dipslay: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i thougt about that option, but it looks like that on my example site its also working without this way.